# How to package sapui5 application for android?

Tags: android, cordova, sapui5

I have created a crossplatform mobile application using sapui5 in eclipse IDE.
Please guide me for packaging it for android using cordova.

Thanks ,
Esha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To include the SAPUI5 resources you need in your hybrid app, SAPUI5 mobile provides the following static mobile runtime packages: `sapui5-mobile-opt-static.zip` or `sapui5-mobile-static.zip`.
For the API documentation you can check the below link

[Running SAPUI5 Mobile Apps in Hybrid Web Containers](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/guide/293eb945f0e945aaa776812481b4c533.html)

Hopefully you are looking for something like this:

[SAP and mobile powers combined through SAPUI5 and PhoneGap](http://scn.sap.com/community/developer-center/front-end/blog/2013/04/06/sap-and-mobile-powers-combined-through-sapui5-and-phonegap)

This is explained with Phonegap Build for packaging of app. But there is limitation of Phonegap Build, it is restricted to one app packaing per account. For more than one you have to pay to phonegap. However it wont be a problem for you simply can check phonegap site and do packaging by your own using Eclipse ADT and cordova jar.

You can also check,

[Building awesome mobile apps with SAPUI5 and PhoneGap](http://scn.sap.com/community/technology-innovation/blog/2012/05/11/sapui5--building-mobile-apps-together-with-phonegap)

There is one more detailed, step by step explantion including installation of all the required softwares. Please check this link, it is for SAP HANA but for sure will be helpful to you.

[Complete Guide](http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/scn/go/portal/prtroot/docs/library/uuid/c09bea9c-359d-3010-3086-ce157711618d?QuickLink=index&overridelayout=true&58879706665749)

Hope this help you with your problem...!!!!